# Invalid reference to named queries (WITH CLAUSE)

Tags: sql, oracle

The below is what I have

```
WITH T as 
(SELECT columns 
from table)
select columns 
from T 
where recordid = 123
and <certain conditions met>
exception
when no_data_found then
select columns 
from T
where recordid = 123
and <some other conditions met>
```

my requirement is to check for few conditions which if not met then i need to check for other conditions on the same record.

without the exception block all works fine but when I use the exception block, it throws me an error that the defined query columns cannot be referenced in there

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions. The answer here will probably depend on what kind of conditions _certain conditions met_ are...

Answer (score 2):

The sub-query factoring (`WITH`) clause only exists for the single statement. If you want to have the same sub-query in another statement then you will have to duplicate the sub-query factoring clause:

```
DECLARE                          -- Declare the PL/SQL variables
  v_columns TABLE.COLUMNS%TYPE;
BEGIN
  WITH T (columns) as (
    SELECT columns 
    from table
  )
  select columns
  INTO   v_columns                -- In PL/SQL you need to SELECT ... INTO ...
                                  -- a variable.
  from   T 
  where  recordid = 123
  and <certain conditions met>;   -- statement terminator
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    WITH T (columns) as (          -- Duplicate the sub-query factoring clause
                                   -- for the next statement
      SELECT columns 
      from table
    )
    select columns
    INTO v_columns                 -- Again, you need to SELECT ... INTO a variable.
    from T
    where recordid = 123
    and <some other conditions met>; -- Statement terminator
END;
/
```

Comment: @MTO Thank you so much for the quick response. yes I have already factored in the INTO clause just had to omit in the question to make it less confusing. Also regarding defining it multiple times, I believe I can use a FUNC/PROCEDURE and then call it multiple times right? the reason being that my main WITH clause is actually a pivot query and i do not want to write it multiple times.

Comment: @mumbai007 You could possibly use either: a `MATERIALIZED VIEW`; a temporary table; or `BULK COLLECT INTO` a collection. If you call a function or procedure multiple times then the queries inside will be run multiple times (there are exceptions if the function is `DETERMINISTIC` or uses `RESULT_CACHE` but I can't see how either would help you). You would be better to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with a [MRE] describing the actual problem (rather than the XY-problem of trying to re-use a `WITH` clause).